# JMeter Beanshell Sampler - Not setting properties values

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am using a JMeter Beanshell Sampler to preload a properties file:

```
'''FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("${PROPERTIES_FILE}"));
   props.load(is);
   is.close();'''
```

However, on the first run some of the values are not set? When I run again it sets all the values.

JMeter First Run - Response code:

```
'''Response message:javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL:tcp://:61616?keepAlive=true.'''
```

The IP Address was not set within the properties file.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think JMS test elements are being initialized **before any Sampler is executed** (including the Beanshell Sampler)

So I would recommend:

1. Removing your Beanshell Sampler completely
2. Passing the .properties file via `-q` [command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -q /path/to/your/file.properties -t testplan.jmx ....
   ```

Also be informed that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so going forward consider using Groovy, more information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)